# For r.v. Z = max(X1, ..., Xn), what is $f_Z(z)$, given X1, X2, ..., Xn are independent.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, order-statistics

[image: problem 4.36]

I'm trying to understand the problem in the picture above.

What happened to the "dz" between this step:

$$f(Z)~ dz~ \Bigg( \int \limits_{-\infty}^{z} f(x)~dx \Bigg)^{n-1}$$

and this step:

$$f_Z(z) = 2~f(z) \int \limits_{-\infty}^{z} f(x)~dx = 2~f(z)~F(z)$$

---

A few properties that I know:

- for continuous r.v. $P(X=x) = 0$
- $P(a < X \le b) = \int \limits_{b}^{a} f_X(x)~dx$
- Max(a, b) = (a > b) ? a : b
- Max(a, b, c)

```
  Max(a,b,c) =   
    if (a >= b) and (a >= c): 
        largest = a 

    elif (b >= a) and (b >= c): 
        largest = b 
    else: 
        largest = c 

    return largest
```

Comment: Probability is always probability density times $dz$. The second equality is not a probability, so no $dz$ is there.

Comment: $\lim \limits_{dz \to 0} P(z <Z< z+dz)$  does this have meaning?

Answer (score 1):

**RULE: Converting infinitesimal probability into PDF**

When converting an infinitesimal probability into a PDF, remove the dx:

$$\underbrace{P(x < X < x + dx) = f_X(x)~dx}_\text{infinitesimal probability} \longleftrightarrow \underbrace{f_X(x)}_\text{PDF}$$